# Type trait for any templated types with constant values

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I'm currently making a code that needs a specific implementation for any type that has templates, so I'm trying to code a type trait that is true for any templated type.

Right now, I've got this:

```
template<class T> 
struct TIsTemplated { enum { Value = 0 }; };

template<template<typename, typename...> class T, typename First, typename... Values> 
struct TIsTemplated<T<First, Values...>> { enum { Value = 1 }; };
```

This works well for templated types like

```
template<typename T>
struct X { };
```

It fails however as soon as there is a type that has constant values:

```
template<typename T, int i = 10>
struct Y {};
```

I found out I could make a type like:

```
template<int A, template<typename, int> class T, typename First> 
struct TIsTemplated<T<First,A>> { enum { Value = 1 }; };
```

However, this only works if I know upfront that I'll have a type that takes an `int`. I've tried to generalize this:

```
template<typename C>
template<C A, template<typename, C> class T, typename First> 
struct TIsTemplated<T<First,A>> { enum { Value = 1 }; };
```

But even though this compiles correctly, `TIsTemplated` still is false for type `Y`. Is there any way to achieve this without having to know the constant type?

Comment: Can you give context asto why you think you need to do this?  This is like saying "regardless of its current properties, I need to identify all bricks manufactured in the southern half of their respective state".

Comment: I'm generating some bindings from C++ to another language, and while most types can use a generalized implementation, templated types need to have an implementation for each type. I need somehow to find a way to tell the C++ compiler not to use the default implementation on these cases. For context, the project is https://github.com/proletariatgames/unreal.hx , and while templates work currently, I'm revisiting how they are handled so we can generate less glue code garbage

Comment: Why would it need an implementation for each type?  If you are binding a template, that is one thing, but if you are binding a type generated by a template, why does that imply binding every type that can be generated by said template?  A type being generated by a template is an implementation detail.  Second, are there a finite list of such templates you need to wrap?  You can relatively easily wrap a given template (or "template pattern") with hedroginous template parameter "kinds" into one that only takes types, then solve the type-only template problem.

Comment: It needs a special implementation because haxe doesn't support templates the same way as C++ does - so in order to be able to make C++ templated types accessible from Haxe, we'd need to find a way to erase them. And yes there is a finite number of templates, and listing them exhaustively is the "next best" way to deal with this. I wanted to avoid it though, because changing this list would mean that all glues would have to be recompiled

Comment: Ok!  Next questions: How are you going to get a "representative" of each template type if you don't, say, list them somewhere, and how is this different than listing the templates?  Next, given that you are erasing them, don't you only support a finite list of scalar types anyhow -- why do you need to support an arbitrary scalar type in your template-recognizer?  Are the only type of template that contains scalars you want to erase of the `template<class, Scalar>class` pattern for some integral type `Scalar`?

Comment: If I can tell C++ to not use the default implementation for these types, I'll provide an implementation for them only when this exact type is needed (ie by including the implementation header for the type that is needed), so we don't have to rebuild all glue code if the list changes. And yes, I'd only need for the case you mentioned above. All other cases can already be represented with the above implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
```

is a bundle of types.

```
template<class Scalar, class T>
struct is_template_with_scalar : std::false_type {};

template<class Scalar, template<class,Scalar>class Z, class U, Scalar s>
struct is_template_with_scalar<Scalar, Z<U,s>> : std::true_type {};
```

Is a test given a `Scalar` type, does the type `T` match the pattern `template<class, Scalar>`.

We then curry it a bit:

```
template<class Scalar>
struct scalar_test {
  template<class T>
  using result=is_template_with_scalar<Scalar, T>;
};
```

This takes a bunch of bool types, and evaluates their logical or:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct or_types : std::false_type {};

template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct or_types<T0, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<bool, T0{} || or_types<Ts...>{} >
{};
```

`passes_any` takes a list of types, and a meta-test that takes a type.  It produces a test that states if any of the tests are passed:

```
template<class List, template<class>class Test>
struct passes_any {};

template<class...Ts, template<class>class Test>
struct passes_any<types<Ts...>, Test> {
  template<class U>
  using result=or_types< typename Test<Ts>::template result<U>... >;
};
```

Now, we start with:

```
using scalars_supported = types<int, char, std::size_t, unsigned>; // etc
```

And we get a test:

```
template<class T>
using is_scalar_template = 
  typename passes_any<scalars_supported,scalar_test>::template result<T>;
```

which given a type `T` is a truthy type if it is an instance of a template with the pattern `<class, Scalar>` for any `Scalar` in the `scalars_supported` list.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6901f1d5805d6a1)

Comment: I can't thank you enough! That implementation is amazing!